# gcc appears to be misconfigured in macOS Big Sur

Tags: clang, macos-big-sur, xcode-command-line-tools

I've been trying to build GCC 10.2 on my Intel MBP. As I've always done, I'm building from source and installing on /usr/local. Trouble is no matter what, the build fails on STAGE2 of bootstrapping. A careful search on all logs (including dependencies) could not point to a single fault. The only thing that stood out was the clang setup from Xcode Command Line Tools. When I run 'gcc -v' on a clean system (empty /usr/local), it outputs:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Trouble is that the target for --with-gxx-include-dir doesn't exist! There is no c++ subfolder, to begin with. Although there is one from the --prefix tree, instead of 4.2.1, there is just a v1 subfolder.

It would appear that there is something terribly wrong with Xcode Command Line Tools. But I can't be sure that this is the cause of my own troubles.

Please, don't answer this post pointing me to a package manager... there's a reason I abandoned those years ago. Also, it would be off-topic to the issue at hand.

Comment: The installed `cc` is only used in stage 1, right?  So if you made it to stage 2 then this is not the problem.  (My guess is that it is not a problem at all, and that its headers are simply in some other directory which is also searched, perhaps `/usr/include`.)  I strongly suspect your problem is something else.

Comment: is it gcc at all? Is it not clang?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to isolate the issue. GCC 10.2 depends on GMP, MPFR, MPC, and ISL libraries. I had them manually installed with the latest version available and fine tuned to my system. I didn't explore if it was a version conflict, or a fine tuning issue, but that broke the build. The solution was to let the script 'contrib/download_prerequisites' (within gcc tree) download the appropriate versions that were built along with GCC.

I also found out that the '--with-gxx-include-dir' target is a non-issue. It isn't supposed to point anywhere in my system. It is a reference to the system that built the "gcc" provided by Xcode Command Line Tools.